# For an acute angled triangle $ABC,$ if $p=\frac{\sqrt3+\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}{2\sin A\sin B\sin C}$, find the range of $p$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality, maxima-minima, geometric-inequalities

$$ p=\frac{\sqrt3+\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}{2\sin A\sin B\sin C}$$

$\displaystyle \sin A+\sin B+\sin C=4\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2}$ and

$\displaystyle \sin A\sin B\sin C=8\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2}\sin\frac{A}{2}\sin\frac{B}{2}\sin\frac{C}{2}$ in a triangle

$A<90^\circ, \text{so} \space A/2<45^\circ$ then $ \sin\frac{A}{2}<1/\sqrt2$. However, $$ \cos\frac{A}{2}>1/\sqrt2$$

So this probably doesn't lead us anywhere :( .

Can anyone please help, thanks.

Comment: Source of the question, please?

Comment: @Buraian, I found this in a jee advanced mock test https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Entrance_Examination_–_Advanced

Comment: Some rearranging gives $\displaystyle p=\frac{\sqrt 3}{8\Pi\cos\frac{ A}{2}(2\Pi\sin \frac{A}{2}-1)}$

Comment: A way to solve this without much thought would be to use lagrange multipliers

Comment: Can you post a solution using Lagrange multipliers ? @Buraian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lower bound.

For $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=60^{\circ}$ we obtain a value $\frac{10}{3}$.

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, in the standard notation we need to prove that $$\sqrt3+\sum_{cyc}\frac{2S}{bc}\geq\frac{20}{3}\cdot\frac{8S^3}{a^2b^2c^2}$$ or
$$\sqrt3+\frac{2S(a+b+c)}{abc}\geq\frac{160S^3}{3a^2b^2c^2}.$$
Here $S$ is the area of the triangle

Now, let $a=\frac{y+z}{2}$, $b=\frac{x+z}{2}$ and  $c=\frac{x+y}{2}$.

Thus, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives and we need to prove that:
$$\sqrt3+\frac{4\sqrt{xyz(x+y+z)^3}}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}\geq\frac{160\sqrt{x^3y^3z^3(x+y+z)^3}}{3\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)^2}$$ or
$$\prod_{cyc}(x+y)+12\sqrt{xyz\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3}\geq\frac{160\sqrt{x^3y^3z^3(x+y+z)^3}}{3\sqrt3\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}.$$
Now, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\prod_{cyc}(x+y)+12\sqrt{xyz\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3}=2\cdot\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}{2}+3\cdot4\sqrt{xyz\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3}\geq$$
$$\geq5\sqrt[5]{\left(\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}{2}\right)^2\left(4\sqrt{xyz\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3}\right)^3}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$5\sqrt[5]{\left(\frac{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}{2}\right)^2\left(4\sqrt{xyz\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3}\right)^3}\geq\frac{160\sqrt{x^3y^3z^3(x+y+z)^3}}{3\sqrt3\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}$$ or
$$3^6\prod_{cyc}(x+y)^{14}\geq2^{42}(xyz)^{12}(x+y+z)^6.$$
Now, use $$\prod_{cyc}(x+y)\geq\frac{8}{9}(x+y+z)(xy+xz+yz)\geq\frac{8}{9}(x+y+z)\sqrt{3xyz(x+y+z)}$$ and $$x+y+z\geq3\sqrt[3]{xyz}.$$
The upper bound is $+\infty$.

Try $\alpha=\beta\rightarrow\left(90^{\circ}\right)^-$ and $\gamma\rightarrow\left(0^{\circ}\right)^+$.

Comment: What does S denote?

Comment: @Lalit Tolani It's an area of the triangle.

Comment: $\sqrt3+\frac{2S(a+b+c)}{abc}\geq\frac{160S^3}{3a^2b^2c^2}$, how did you simplify the original expression to this one, and are a,b,c the sides of the triangle

Comment: @Sunaina  We know that $S=\frac{1}{2}bc\sin\alpha$, which gives $\sin\alpha=\frac{2S}{bc}.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, I've noticed something else (though not exactly related to this question), in many inequality questions (not all) we can get the minimum/maximum value if we substitute a=b=c=d.... (depending on the number of variables). Is there a theorem for this (i.e a function must satisfy certain properties for this to be true), or is it completely arbitrary and random.

Comment: @Sunaina It's not so in the general. Also, does not exist a general theorem, for which the equality occurs for equality case of any variables. Otherwise, it's some statement , which helps to solve some problems, but does not help in the general.