# Minimum and maximum value of $P= {{\sqrt 3} + \sin A + \sin B + \sin C } \over { 2 {\sin A}{\sin B}{\sin C}} $ using Lagrange multipliers .

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

We have to find the Minimum and maximum value of $$P= {{\sqrt 3} + \sin A + \sin B + \sin C } \over { 2 {\sin A}{\sin B}{\sin C}} $$ using Lagrange multipliers , where ABC is a triangle .

I know the solution using $\sin {A} = {a \over {2R}} $ and other trigonometric properties . This question has already been asked on the forum , but someone mentioned using Lagrange multiplier would be a much easier and helpful way .

But myself have not been able to do so ,so please post a solution using Lagrange multipliers if possible .

**My attempt**  so I try to express $\sin C$ in terms of $\sin A$ and $\sin B $

$$\sin C = \sin ({{\pi - { (A +B)}}}) = \sin {( A +B )} = \sin A{ \sqrt{ 1- \sin^2 B } + { \sin B}{ \sqrt { 1 - \sin^2 A}} } $$

Now I don't know what to do further .

Comment: Please show your effort,.. like expressing sin C in terms of sin A and sin B to convert it to a two independent  variable problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237105/for-an-acute-angled-triangle-abc-if-p-frac-sqrt3-sin-a-sin-b-sin-c2-s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For an acute angled triangle $ABC,$ if $p=\frac{\sqrt3+\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}{2\sin A\sin B\sin C}$, find the range of $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4237105/for-an-acute-angled-triangle-abc-if-p-frac-sqrt3-sin-a-sin-b-sin-c2-s)

Comment: I clearly stated I wanted a solution based on Lagrange multipliers because I knew that a solution already exists ,but through a different method @TheBestMagician

Comment: @Sukhoi234 Use Lagrange multipliers on the inequality in that question.